# Process Exits immediately if I redirect a Console Application written in Delphi in C# winform application

Tags: c#, delphi, console, io-redirection

I have a console application (Host.exe) that is written in Delphi.
I want to redirect the output of the console application in C# application (WinForm).

If I use the following, the (Host.exe) is invoked without problems, but it is not possible to get the output since it is run as (show-window, quite independent).

```
                ProcessStartInfo pp = new ProcessStartInfo();
                pp.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
                pp.FileName = Path.Combine(pp.WorkingDirectory, "Host.exe");
                pp.CreateNoWindow = false;
                pp.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
                pp.UseShellExecute = true;
                using (Process pProcess = Process.Start(pp))
                {
                    while ((pProcess != null) && (!pProcess.HasExited))
                    {
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        Thread.Sleep(updatefreq);
                    }
                }
```

However, if I try to capture the output (redirection), the process will exit immediately (HasExited = true, the loop breaks, the debugger shows, "Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed".

```
                ProcessStartInfo pp = new ProcessStartInfo();
                pp.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
                pp.FileName = Path.Combine(pp.WorkingDirectory, "Host.exe");
                pp.UseShellExecute = false;
                pp.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                pp.RedirectStandardInput = true;
                pp.RedirectStandardError = true;
                pp.CreateNoWindow = true;
                pp.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                StreamReader outputReader = null;
                using (Process pProcess = Process.Start(pp))
                {
                    if (pProcess != null)
                    {
                        //StreamWriter inputWriter = pProcess.StandardInput;
                        //StreamReader errorReader = pProcess.StandardError;
                        outputReader = pProcess.StandardOutput;
                    }
                    while ((pProcess != null) && (!pProcess.HasExited))
                    {
                        string ss = null;
                        if (outputReader != null)
                        {
                            ss = outputReader.ReadLine();
                        }
                        if ((ss != null) && (2 < ss.Length))
                        {
                            string[] s = ss.Split('|');
                            if (3 == s.Length)
                            {
                                float global;
                                //float.TryParse(s[0], out local);
                                float.TryParse(s[1], out global);
                                RadioTracer.SetCurrentMsg(s[2]);
                                RadioTracer.SetCurrentStep((int)global);
                            }
                        }
                        Application.DoEvents();
                        Thread.Sleep(updatefreq);
                    }
                }
```

I have googled a lot but haven't got the solution.
the following pages present similar problems, and I've tried the suggested solutions but nothing works.

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/609801/unable-to-redirect-only-the-standard-input-of-process-cmd-exe-or-batch-file-from-windows-form-application

http://go4answers.webhost4life.com/Example/redirectstandardinput-a-32-bit-114440.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/4f946750-6c47-406c-810c-21a2b103b5c4

Thanks a lot... this wastes me a lot of time already.. I hope I can get a solution here.

**EDIT:** The problem still exists even I don't use any ReadLine() or ReadToEnd() method. When 'UseShellExecute' set to false, the Host.exe will exit immediately.. The Host.exe is supposed to do some big computation (takes around 2 minutes and report progress through console WriteLine every few seconds).

Comment: Here's an example that seems to work as you described you want yours to work -- http://blog.csharphelper.com/2010/11/10/run-a-dos-application-and-capture-its-output-in-c.aspx -- they use `ReadToEnd()` to get all of the `stdout` instead of using `ReadLine()`...

Comment: The ReadLine() or ReadToEnd() should not matter in this case, because the Host.exe will exit automatically if 'UseShellExecute' set to false, even if I don't ReadLine() or ReadToEnd() at all...

Comment: Your code is a little fussy. You don't need so many tests for null. And you are missing a using around pProcess.StandardOutput. But your code does actually work. Try it will a Delphi console app that loops doing Writeln followed by Sleep, Writeln, Sleep etc. So I don't see how we can help. Something weird about host.exe perhaps. But we don't have host.exe. Perhaps it's UAC?

Comment: Thanks.. Yes. You are right... The logic of C# code is all right because I have created a simple Host.exe that just prints out progress/message, and it works all right.. The UAC is turned off completely. Maybe there is something wrong with the Host.exe but I couldn't figure out why, because Host.exe works all right under command line...

Comment: I have found the cause, please see 'the answer'

Comment: Well done. It was much as I outlined!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the following lines will cause errors if you redirect the output in C#. I am using a Console.pas unit in Delphi that in Initialization of that unit, it invokes InitScreenMode procedure.

```
  Reset(Input);
  Rewrite(Output);
  StdIn := TTextRec(Input).Handle;
  StdOut := TTextRec(Output).Handle;
```

I am guessing 'Reset' or 'Rewrite' the Console stdin/stdout will cause problems when 'UseShellExecute' set to false in C#

Comment: "any explanation for this?" Looks like you're asking a new question in an answer, but that's not the way StackOverflow works, please read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). You may want to edit your original question and include this bit of information, or maybe ask a new question. That's up to you, but you don't ask new questions in answers.

Comment: In traditional pascal files, reset opens the file for Input, while rewrite opens the file for output. I'm pretty sure any console application have to _open_ the input/output streams to use it. It happens at the low level, and you're looking inside the console.pas unit which is the one that implements this low level thing. I guess your guess is wrong, but I'm not expert in this, thus, like you, I just comment what I think.

Comment: thanks... I think Reset(Input) conflicts the redirection in C#,, but since it is low level, I don't know the details and reasons why it doesn't work. Anyway, I've removed the unit (or simply comment out Reset) and it works perfectly as I expect.